# Error IdentityNotMappedException was unhandled

Tags: vb.net, file

I want to create folder that will only be accessible by the owner.
I've tried to do that and got this code Error `IdentityNotMappedException was unhandled`.
The folder will be create at the server drive and I had mapped the server drive To a local drive.

```
 Dim fs As FileSystemSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(Q_FilePath)
 fs.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule("Owner", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny))
 File.SetAccessControl(Q_FilePath, fs)
```